# Добавление модуля в Python для запуска exe файла

Tags: python, pygame, exe

Недавно столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Захотел отправить другу игру, написанию на python с помощью модуля Pygame. Игру я конвертировал из .py в .exe, при этом в папке с игрой, как и пологается есть все .png файлы и так далее. Но игра не запустилась на компьютере друга, причиной тому стала отсутствие установленного модуля pygame на его ПК. Можно ли в папку с игрой добавить какой-нибудь файл, чтобы игра запускалась без установленного на ПК python или pygame?

Comment: Зависит от того как и чем вы создавали .exe файл

Comment: есть ответ на enSF -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210392/how-can-i-convert-pygame-to-exe

Comment: модуль py2exe, при создании исполняемого файла, создаёт архив с локальной версией питона и требуемых модулей